# How to let people download files on my website?

Tags: django, python-3.x, apache, ubuntu, permissions

My site should scrape some data from another, everything worked on my computer. Once I put my app on a server and this error occurs. I changed permission to `777` for whole path folders and didn't work. I'm using `python3`, `apache 2.4` on `ubuntu 18.10`.

> PermissionError at /scrape/ [Errno 13] Permission denied: FILENAME

Error log:

```
[Tue Sep 24 20:54:41.981186 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 29114:tid 139877711529728] [remote 89.78.216.206:53391]   File "/home/matms/django_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
[Tue Sep 24 20:54:41.981190 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 29114:tid 139877711529728] [remote 89.78.216.206:53391]     response = get_response(request)
[Tue Sep 24 20:54:41.981192 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 29114:tid 139877711529728] [remote 89.78.216.206:53391]   File "/home/matms/django_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
[Tue Sep 24 20:54:41.981195 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 29114:tid 139877711529728] [remote 89.78.216.206:53391]     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
[Tue Sep 24 20:54:41.981198 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 29114:tid 139877711529728] [remote 89.78.216.206:53391]   File "/home/matms/django_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
[Tue Sep 24 20:54:41.981201 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 29114:tid 139877711529728] [remote 89.78.216.206:53391]     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
[Tue Sep 24 20:54:41.981204 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 29114:tid 139877711529728] [remote 89.78.216.206:53391]   File "/home/matms/django_project/news/views.py", line 96, in scrape
[Tue Sep 24 20:54:41.981207 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 29114:tid 139877711529728] [remote 89.78.216.206:53391]     with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
[Tue Sep 24 20:54:41.981211 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 29114:tid 139877711529728] [remote 89.78.216.206:53391] PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '4MsktkpTURBXy9kOWRiYWQ4Yzk2ZDkyYjk2YjNiYmRhZjNhNDdiMWQ2NC5qcGeTlQMARc0EAM0CP5MFzQEUzJuVB9kyL3B1bHNjbXMvTURBXy83MWUxOGYwMDNhYWE1ODk3NTIwMmFmNTk0OGZmNmZjMS5wbmcAwgA.jpg'
[Tue Sep 24 20:54:41.981217 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 29114:tid 139877711529728] [remote 89.78.216.206:53391]
```

Line causing error with:

```
  media_root = '/home/matms/django_project/media_root'
        if not image_source_solved.startswith(("data:image", "javascript")):
            #exists = os.path.isfile(media_root+image_source_solved)
            exists = 1
            if exists == 2:
                pass
            else:
                local_filename = image_source_solved.split('/')[-1].split("?")[0]+".jpg"
                r = session.get(image_source_solved, stream=True, verify=False)
                with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
                    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
                        f.write(chunk)

                current_image_absolute_path = os.path.abspath(local_filename)
                shutil.move(current_image_absolute_path, media_root)
```

Comment: What did you change permissions for? The `media_root` folder?

Comment: All of media_root directory folders: matms etc.

Answer (score 0):

It will throw error until it get the permission for the full path.
Here is your directory structure string.

```
'/home/matms/django_project/media_root'
```

Even if you have changed the permission for `media_root` folder but not of its parent directories i.e `django_project`, `matms` or `home`, it will throw error.

Vice versa also works:
If the application has permission to modify `/home/matms/django_project/` but not `media_root` folder, it will again throw error.

There are chances that you have changed only the permission of `media_root`. You have to change permissions of its parent directories too.

Comment: I know it's a bad practise but i changed chmod to 777 for whole directory folders now, and still getting the same error.

Comment: Are you giving these permissions to the same user, that is running the python script ?

Comment: I want to give these permissions to all people visiting site. I mean they should be able to scrape images by clicking button.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
```

This change solved the problem.

```
from django.conf import settings                    
with open(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, local_filename), 'wb') as f:
```